# AWS Elasticsearch Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aggregation

```
    #   Transaction Id  Amount  Status  
    1   AA001           100     pending 
    2   AA001           100     success 
    3   AA002           200     pending
```

On above data **AA001** - having both **pending** & **success** AA002 have only **pending**

So expected to get as below

```
    #   Transaction Id  Amount  Status  
    2   AA001           100     success 
    3   AA002           200     pending
```

How to apply Aggregation?

**Condition:**

```
- if a transaction have both pending and success status record return only success record
- if a transaction have only pending return pending record
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can sort the way you want , and a rank to each row. Pick the rank = 1 , so you pick only one row for a unique combination of transaction id and amount.